# how to append on to this array with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, push

when you say new it should add the item you enter to the todo list and when I call list it should give me the list but the quit works and it quits the program if you have any advice can you please tell me how to fix this problem thank you in advance

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
    while(true){
        var rep = prompt("what ya wanna do?");
        var list = [];

        if(rep === "new"){
            var newItem = prompt("whacha wanna add?")
            list.push(newItem);
        }

        if(rep === "list"){
            alert(list)
        }
    
        if(rep === "quit"){
            break;
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="ps3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>"new" - Add A Todo</li>
        <li>"list" - Veiw All Todos</li>
        <li>"quit" - Quit Applet</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should consider removing that `while` loop

Comment: but I want it to keep asking until i say "quit"

Comment: consider using a `do...while`

Comment: thank you for you contributions but the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable  `var list = [];` **outside** the while loop

Working example

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
        var list = [];
    while(true){
        var rep = prompt("what ya wanna do?");

        if(rep === "new"){
            var newItem = prompt("whacha wanna add?")
            list.push(newItem);
        }

        if(rep === "list"){
            alert(list)
        }
    
        if(rep === "quit"){
            break;
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="ps3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>"new" - Add A Todo</li>
        <li>"list" - Veiw All Todos</li>
        <li>"quit" - Quit Applet</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yup in 5 mins i will

Answer (score 0):

Declare list to be out of while loop

```js
var list = [];
window.setTimeout(function() {
    while(true){
        var rep = prompt("what ya wanna do?");
        

        if(rep === "new"){
            var newItem = prompt("whacha wanna add?")
            list.push(newItem);
        }

        if(rep === "list"){
            alert(list)
        }
    
        if(rep === "quit"){
            break;
        }
    }
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="ps3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>"new" - Add A Todo</li>
        <li>"list" - Veiw All Todos</li>
        <li>"quit" - Quit Applet</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```